# Centering Text Inside a Section

Tags: html, css, center

[image]

I want to bring the text "menu" into the center of the page.
I'm new at html and I'm sure it's simple but I  just can't figure it out.

```css
    body{
     background-color:#163350;
    background-repeat: repeat-x; 
    margin: 0;
    }



    header {
        background-color:#ded7c2;
        color:white;
        text-align:center;
        padding:5px; 
     
    }
    h1{
     font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace; 
     font-size:30px;
     color: #ffffff; 
     text-align:center;
    } 
    h2{
     font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace; 
     font-size:20px;
     color:#ffffff; 
     text-align:center;
    } 
    p{
     font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:15px;
     color:white;
    }
    nav {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto
      font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace; 
      font-size:12px;
      color: #ffffff; 
      text-align:center;
      line-height:30px;
      background-color:#68594c;
      height:690px;
      width:100px;
      float:left;
      padding:0px; 
    }

    nav img {
      width: 60px;
    }

    nav ul{
      padding: 0;
     list-style-type:none;
     }


    section {
        width:400px;
        float:left;
        padding:10px; 
    }
    footer {
     font-family:"courier new";
     font-size:20px; 
       background-color:#ded7c2;
        color:white;
        clear:both;
        text-align:center;
        padding:5px; 
     width: 100%;
     height:37px;
    }
    img section{
     float:left;
     text-align:center;
    }
    img section two{
     float:center;
     text-align:center;
     }
    img section three
     float:right;
     text-align:center;
     }
```

```html
    <div class= "container">
    <nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="home 3.html"><img src="images/home.png" alt="Home" ></a></li> <br><br><p>
    <li><a href="Menu.html"><img src="images/menu.png" alt="Menu"></a></li><br><br><p>
    <li><a href="Blank.html"><img src="images/blank.png" alt="Blank"></a></li><br><br><p>
    <li><a href="Blank.html"><img src="images/blanktwo.png" alt="Blank"></a></li><br><br><p>
    <li><a href="Blank.html"><img src="images/blank.png" alt="Blank"></a></li>

    </ul>
    </nav>
    <section>

    <h2>Menu</h2>
    <p> <p>text
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>


    </p>
    </section>



    <footer>
    Copyright &copy; Jack  Ranata

    </footer>
```

*Any help would be greatly appreciated.*

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 section {
    width: 100%;

    h2 {
        font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #ffffff;
        width: 100%;
        margin: auto 0;
        text-align: center;
```

Comment: i can see how that would work but its inside a rectangular section. So the text IS actually centered, I just want to enlarge the section across the whole page...

Comment: check my post again. @AnaG

Comment: Did this help at all? @AnaG

Comment: It appears to have worked, apart from the fact that it is now in the literal middle of the page both horizontally and vertically...

Comment: - also the font, size, and colour of the text has defaulted.

Answer (score 0):

in order to solve this problem, it is luckily quite simple.

Since it seems that the 'menu' text is on its own line, you can use this css. I gave the 'menu' text the class `.menu`

```
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  text-align:center;
}
```

What this does is that it makes the h2 tag the full width of the parent container, then it tells itself to align its personal text to the center.

I notice that the parent container of the 'menu' h2 tag is set to 400px, this means that the text will not align perfectly to the middle of the screen. In order for this to work, you MUST make sure that the parent container is the full width of the screen.

Comment: @AnaG Wow, that is very strange. If that doesn't work, try setting the h2 tag to a specific width, then using `margin: 0 auto` to align to the center. This always aligns anything of any width to the center of its parent container.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<center>` tag to do that.

```
<center><h2>Menu</h2></center>
```

Or You can use the inline css style .

```
<h2 style="text-align:center;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">Menu</h2>
```